# Reading or writing with a 4 WD5000AADS drive RAID 5 array drops to 0 speed

Tags: raid, speed, upload, raid-5

**Edit, 10/31**:
Crash-- complete system lockup.  Booted computer, had strange lag for visiting ANY webpage in Chrome.. Figured that either a network problem existed, **or Chrome could not write to disk fast enough..**.  System locked up on viewing a folder of photos before I'd upload them.

On system restart, got an error from the WHEA-Logger with the following XML info:
http://pastebin.com/zJYWWSQJ
I also got:

```
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x00000124  
(0x0000000000000000, 0xfffffa8004ce5478, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000).
```

**Pretty sure that this is a hardware problem.**  Tempted to see if installing a RAID card on my PCI Express 16x will fix the problem.  Not sure if the checkbox-disabling I mention regarding the disk below has decreased my stability..

---

I upload a lot of files to MediaFire and other file sharing services.  This is usually due to the fact I take photos of friends and need a convenient way to share the originals.

When I upload files to Mediafire or any other site, the 'line goes dead'.  They all report that the connection times out.  Looking at the transfer speed bar, it drops down to 0 regularly, and sometimes it doesn't come back soon enough to keep the upload.  I investigated this with other PCs on my network, and this doesn't happen with them.  It's only this main PC that has the drop to zero.

I realized it was likely a harddrive problem when Minecraft regularly froze my entire computer when saving the world to the disk.

So, here's what you might want to know.

- Windows 7, Pro or whatever. 64 bit.
- M4N72-E motherboard from ASUS. (Yeah, it's old news now. :( )
- Which means I have the NVIDIA nForce 750a SLI chipset as my Storage driver.
- I have 4 Western Digital WD5000AADS drives, arranged in a RAID 5 array.
- I updated the storage driver in an attempt to fix the problem.  The update I got is from NVidia.

  - My Storage Driver is 11.1.0.43, same as the RAID driver.
  - My RPT RAID Rom version is 10.0.0.35 (This is probably the firmware on the onboard RAID?)
- All four drive passed the PC's SMART self-test.

**Solutions I've tried:**

- Updating the RAID/storage drivers (see above)
- Disabling the "Windows Cache Flushing"

  - I also tried disabling Windows write caching *at all*.

Also, here's a picture from HD Tuner showing my benchmark:

[image]

Comment: A hard drive problem wouldn't cause a network connection to fail. And your HD Tuner benchmark looks normal.

Comment: If you ignore the minecraft data point, do you have any other symptoms that suggest disk rather than network?

Comment: Thanks for asking, David and Paul.  I tried with other PCs on the network, and there was no such jagged transfer, and transfers didn't time out.

Comment: Related: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @TomWijsman .  Looks like "A Scalable Coherent Interface (SCI) generic error occurred."  .. Obviously corresponding to the disks and the storage controller.